# Using Template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I'm trying to do a generic method in a class, now, I have something like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T returnVal(T value);
}

template<class T>
T Test::returnVal(T value)
{
    return value;
}


int main()
{
    string reference = "stringVal";
    Test ref;
    cout << ref.returnVal<string>(reference);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> Error message: Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before >''template<''

However, it's showing error in call function returnVal (main()), I'm not sure about the validate of this code (I'm learning this). What's wrong with this?

Comment: Your code is too incomplete (missing includes, missing semicolon after class definition, etc.) to tell and you didn't tell what the error is. If nothing else, `returnVal` is `private` and you can't call it from outside of the class.

Comment: And also don't forget to make the function `public`.

Comment: Does it work if you use the generic explicitly?  ref.returnVal<string>(reference);

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: It shouldn't since the definition of `returnVal` is wrong (should be `template <class T> T Test::returnVal(T value)` or similar).

Comment: I'll repeat: You're missing a semicolon after the class definition.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Right...  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a semicolon!

Just put a `;` right after class definition.

```
class Test
{
 ...
};
 ^
 |
 +---- HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles and runs as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    template<class T>
    T returnVal(T value);
};

template<class T>
T Test::returnVal(T value)
{
    return value;
};


int main()
{
    string reference = "stringVal";
    Test ref;
    cout << ref.returnVal<string>(reference);
    return 0;
}
```